# How to print mouse coordinates in VC++ Win32 application?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mouse

I know there is a function `GetCursorPos` and the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` event but can anybody tell me with example code how best to print the mouse coordinates?  I'm not sure how to do this in VC++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know .

```
POINT coord;
GetCursorPos(&coord);
cout << "The mouse is at:" << coord.x << coord.y << endl;
```

Comment: yes i know  .. but i want to print the coordinates on form in vc++ win32 windows application ..

Comment: @Suraj - VC++ is C++ with MFC . So everthing in C++/ Windows SDK works .

Comment: @Sujay I'm using VC++ Win32 application  not MFC

Comment: @Sujay: VC++ doesn't have anything to do with MFC. MFC is a wrapper library that is often included with Visual C++, but they're not related.

Comment: cpoint pt;char text[50];
sprintf(text,"Mouse Position: X=%d, Y=%d",pt.x,pt.y);
  LPCWSTR textmsg = (LPCWSTR)text;
  SetWindowText(hWnd,textmsg); this is wat  i have tried

Comment: @Code Gray - yes they dont correlate , but that was just to help Suraj understand VC++ is a superset through which users can develop Windows application. @Suraj - Paste the code under WM_MOUSEMOVE , and use sprintf ( instead of cout ) to get the string ; and send it to back the caller.

Comment: @sujay can u tell me how to send this to caller ??

Comment: @Suraj - I think this is a basic programming question , StackOverflow or any other forums does not encourage this practice.

Comment: but we are at the initial stage of vc++ so for some sytax reason ... we thought to ask you ... but thnx for response ...

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned, you can get the instantaneous position of the mouse cursor on the screen using `GetCursorPos`.  Here's a sample:

```
POINT pt;
if (!GetCursorPos(&pt)) {
    /* ... handle the error ... */
}
```

You'll need to `#include <windows.h>` to use this code.  Once you have called the function, you can read the mouse coordinates from `pt.x` and `pt.y`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to print coordinates on form ... and the syntax u told works on c++ but for vc++ ???

Comment: Visual C++ is the Microsoft implementation of C++.  It is almost fully standard-compliant, though it has its own idiosyncrasies in a few places.  In general, any C++ code should compile in Visual C++.  As for how to print the coordinates, once you have access to the fields that shouldn't be too difficult.  Just use whatever techniques you normally use to display text or numeric data to display the requisite fields.  Without more information I don't think I can offer any more suggestions.